# ngxFormly - grid-template-columns form not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngx-formly

I updated my project from angular 14 to angular 15 but I used a legacy version of angular material , also I have the migration of the component ngx-formly to 6.1.1 and I used ngx-formly/material-legacy, now I have a problem with the alignment of the forms , the theme is good but the alignment is not good, each input in a line but before was two input in each line.

form before migration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiqbM.png)

form after migration:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCUcK.png)

so problem as exists in the second image is that each input in a row and that is an impact after migration

css example of code:

```
    .formly-container {
display: grid;
&.formly-container-step2, &.formly-container-step3 {
grid-template-columns: 100%;
@media (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
grid-template-columns: 50% 50%; //error here
grid-gap: 10px;

    }
    grid-row-gap: 5px;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

where is this solution please

Comment: any help please